# Inserting all records of a table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I'm running a query like this to add fields from one table into another.

```
 INSERT INTO new_table (Num1, Num2, Num3)
 SELECT Num1, Num2, Num3
 FROM initial_table
```

My table contains many different columns, is there a way to move them all with one command rather than manually type each and every column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables are indentical, columns are in exactly same order and there are no IDENTITY columns you could do this:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT *
  FROM initial_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT *
FROM initial_table
```

Will however not work if you have a identity column in `new_table`.